# Testcafe: Expecting Variable shows Object object or NaN

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to add some numbers that are coming from a DIV but I'm unable to add it cause it gives me an [object object][object object] added together and when I tried to String it gives me an Object object and with Number or ParseInt, I get NaN

Testcode:

```
<div class="test1">
<div> Title </div>
<div>13</div>
</div>
```

When I do this `let patientNum1 = Selector('test').child('div').nth(1).textContent;`and do something like .expect(patienNum1).eql(5) it would actually output "Expected 13 to equal 5" my goal is to get that 13 and add it with another similar divclass (test1) with one another.

My goal stops here:

```
let newNum = patientNum1 + patientNum2;
await t
.expect(newNum).eql(15);
AssertionError: expected '[object Object][object Object]' to deeply
      equal 15
```

```
let newNum = parseInt(patientNum1) + parseInt(patientNum2);
await t
.expect(newNum).eql(15);
1) AssertionError: expected NaN to deeply equal 15
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect one or both of `patientNum1` and `patientNum2` are not what you think they are.

Comment: When I run just .expect(patientNum1).eql(13) that works just fine; and doing a typeof for that variable gives me an object. What are some alternatives I should try?

Comment: What about `patientNum2`? Have you verified that it's the value you think it is?

Comment: Yup; its getting the "number" that I'm seeing from the div and running with the expect I get this 1) AssertionError: expected '23' to deeply equal 5 and when I change the .eql to .eql('23') that passes fine

Answer (score 1):

One of your variables isn't what you think it is.

```js
const p1 = document.querySelector('.test > :first-child').textContent;
const p2 = document.querySelector('.test > :last-child').textContent;
let p3;

console.log(p1); // 13
console.log(p2); // 5
console.log( p1 + p2 ); // 135 (concatenated strings)
console.log( parseInt(p1) + parseInt(p2) ); // 18
console.log( parseInt(p1) + parseInt(p3) ); // NaN
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>13</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Added the following sample to demonstrate a possible approach for doing this 
soft of thing for multiple elements:

```js
// utility for parsing ints from dom elements.
// throws on NaN
function asInt (element) {
  const intValue = parseInt(element.textContent);
  if (isNaN(intValue)) {
    throw new Error('unable to parse number');
  }
  return intValue;
}

function doSomethingInteresting () {
  // get the elements where class="patient"
  const patients = document.querySelectorAll('.patient');
  
  // iterate over each 'patient' (each <li> in this case)
  patients.forEach((patient, index) => {

    // look for child nodes with class="value"
    // and extract their contents as integers via map(asInt)
    const numbers = [...patient.querySelectorAll('.value')].map(asInt);
    
    // compute the sum of the numbers for this 'patient'
    const sum = numbers.reduce((acc, v) => (acc + v), 0);
    
    // do whatever you need to do with the result
    console.log(`patient ${index}: ${sum}`);
  })
}

// go
doSomethingInteresting();
```

```css
.patient {
  display: flex;
}

.patient > * {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  margin: 16px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="patient">
    <div class="value">13</div>
    <div class="value">5</div>
  </li>
  <li class="patient">
    <div class="value">26</div>
    <div class="value">15</div>
  </li>
  <li class="patient">
    <div class="value">14</div>
    <div class="value">3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="patient">
    <div class="value">16</div>
    <div class="value">99</div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: How would I write it if I wanted to get the same Div but from a different class called Test? Like I have 4 divs but they're all class "test" but the values inside are different? like your example has 13 and 5 on the first test div but the 2nd test div has 23 and 10

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but I've added another snippet in my answer above to demonstrate one possible approach for summing a series of elements each containing some values.

Comment: I tried doing ".class > :first-child".textContent and that outputs just fine but when I tried to .String() it I get an object object and when I do parseInt() I'm getting NaN. regardless of string and parseInt; it looks like it gets the textcontent just fine but it won't let me convert it to a number.

Comment: Without seeing your code I don’t how else to help you. I stand by my assertion that your variables aren’t what you think they are. Spit them out to the console or set a breakpoint and see what’s happening. The answer will present itself.

Comment: Okay so I got it to work; I followed your approach on Codepen and typeof outputted string but it would do object on Testcafe; so I added await in front of Selector and that did the trick! I Also got them to add up and now outputs a number instead of object or NaN; I think it might have something to do with Testcafe Selector function but I got it to work now, thanks for your advice!